css.modules doesn't scope css styles
Question:
I'm currently developing a React application and using CSS Modules to scope styles locally to each component. However, despite importing only the intended CSS Module for each page, some pages are still receiving styles from other CSS Modules.
Issue:
In my application, each React component has its corresponding CSS Module file (e.g., Register.module.css for Register.jsx). Despite this, the Register page is receiving an overflow-x: hidden style defined in Home.module.css, which is not imported into Register.jsx.
Folders Structure:
https://i.sstatic.net/ykCsle70.png
Importing the CSS Module:
https://i.sstatic.net/ykCsle70.png
Home CSS:
https://i.sstatic.net/M6ObwF1p.png
What I’ve Tried:
I have verified that only the relevant CSS Module is imported in each page component.
I checked the CSS Module files to ensure that there are no global styles defined.
Question:
How can I ensure that styles defined in one CSS Module do not inadvertently affect other pages or components?

I actually missed the second picture, but the code in the register.module.css file is * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
